# MySQL Error: Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1

Tags: mysql, floating-point

MySQL

```
create table tran (
id int,
amount float(9,3)
);

insert into tran (id, amount) values (1, -1000000)
;
```

Error: Out of range value for column 'amount' at row 1

The amount of -1000000 is 7 digits, so wouldnt the 9 in the float be more than enough?

The manual says 
"(M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa6cc

Comment: See the manual, where it talks about scale and precision. It's also unlikely that an amount column in a tran table would be float instead of decimal

Comment: Yes it is wrong that it is a float, but this is a legacy system designed long ago that I cannot change at this time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`FLOAT(9,3)` means:

- 9 *total* units of precision
- with 3 units past the decimal place, hence
- only 6 units *before* the decimal place

If you want 9 digits of non-decimal precision then use `FLOAT(12, 3)`.

Have a look at the MySQL [**documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html).