# How can I receive float from the string number

Tags: php, string, decimal

I have the string **"508 519 401,00"**
If i use (`float`) function I receive **508519401.0** (With one 0)
But I need to set in db `decimal` (10,2) value in this case I need to receive clear 508519401.00 decimal value, How can I get this?

Comment: I receive double with one 0, I was edited my message, sorry about spaces it was true

Comment: I receive the string in this case And I need Decimal

Comment: Because I get This Error http://prntscr.com/imau07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can count only on *a formatted version of number* (as a string).

With `sprintf()` function:

```
$s = "508 519 401,00";
$result = sprintf("%.2F", str_replace(" ", "", $s));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
508519401.00
```

Comment: @David, don't bind your SQL problems to the current Php question

Comment: It helps me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **number_format()** function **like:**

```
<?php 
$string = "508 519 401,01";
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
$string = str_replace(',', '.', $string);
$numb = number_format(round((float)$string, 2), 2, '.', '');
echo($numb);
?>
```

Comment: Here I receive the string Adn I need to get decimal to put into DB

Comment: Because I get This Error prntscr.com/imau07

Comment: @David what is your fieldtype , check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216642/warning1264out-of-range-error-in-mysql) , [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090167/mysql-error-out-of-range-value-for-column-amount-at-row-1) and Have a look at the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)